# laravel diffForHumans(now()) me escribe 1 dia antes en vez de hace 1 dia

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, carbon

Estoy usando $consulta->created_at->diffForHumans(now()) para intentar conseguir que me muestre por ejemplo "Hace 1 día" pero el resultado que me da es "1 día antes" e probado a cambiar el idioma pero nada me dicen lo mismo en ingles por ejemplo 1 day before a que se puede deber y como lo puedo cambiar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estás comparando dos valores (cuando le pasas una fecha en el primer parámetro, es considerado un valor, sin importar que sea la fecha actual).

Si deseas que te aparezca: hace X tiempo, no debes pasar ningún parámetro, puesto que el valor por defecto en la comparación es la fecha y hora actual (ahora).

```
$consulta->created_at->diffForHumans();
```